# Short form of SHA-1 commit id

Tags: java, eclipse, jgit

What is the JGit equivalent API for the following command

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s"
```

I want to get the short form of SHA-1 commit id and the status of the file for that particular commit.

Comment: Can you explain what %h, %an etc. do and maybe give an example?

Comment: **%H = Commit hash
%an = author name
%ar = author date relative
%s = subject**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JGit's `LogCommand` returns a list of `RevCommit`s from which the information can be obtained.

- commit id: `commit.getId()`
- author name: commit.getAuthor().getName()`
- author date: commit.getAuthor().getWhen()`
- subject: commit.getShortMessage()`

To shorten a Git object id in JGit, you can use the `abbreviate()` method.
For example:

```
RevCommit commit = ...
ObjectId commitId = commit.getId();
String shortId = commitId.abbreviate( 7 ).name();
```

will shorten the given `objectId` to 7 characters.

Comment: How to get the refs of commit. Refs contain information like "**(Head-> master, origin/master)**".

Comment: I think this is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47086943/how-to-find-the-branch-for-a-commit-with-jgit